# Nuxt 3 constantly reloading the server

Tags: nuxt3

I was working on a Nuxt 3 project and everything was going great until today when I tried running the project with `npm run dev`, but the server constantly reloading as shown in the photo below:

[image: screenshot]

I tried deleting .nuxt and node_modules and run `npm install` and `npm run dev`, but got the same issue again. I also deleted the project and cloned it again from Github but again...same issue.

Comment: And what does the console in browser (F12) say? There would probably be some error preventing Nuxt from finishing startup. Nuxt team released v3.4 recently, there might be some new issues.

Comment: I only get the "503 Server Unavailable" error

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out!

The issue was that I accidentally deleted .env file.

PS: in case the issue still occurs for some on you, try upgrading Nuxt to 3.4.1 and downgrading a dependency called "consola" to 3.0.1 .